# What is the paper cut command?

Tags: c#, printing

I am working on **Tapidata SDK and printer spooler data** on C sharp. I got **Paper cut command**, but I don't know what is it. Please explain.

Comment: Never heard of Tapidata, but as it relates in part to receipts and you're talking about printer spooler data, surely the "paper cut" command means exactly what it sounds like? The printer should cut the paper, because the receipt is complete?

Answer (score 2):

The receipt delimiter that indicates the end of a receipt. It is normally the paper cut command. The paper cut command may be different depending on the printers. In general, the following three are commonly used.

```
0x1B 0x69
0x1B 0x64
0x1D 0x56
```

Text printed at the end of receipts. Such text should be unique in a receipt context in the sense that they should be most unlikely to appear as product name. Greetings printed at the end of a receipt, such as "Thank you for your visit", "Have a nice day", can often be used. To add text delimiters, please use the API function: `addStrDelimiter(string  delim)`. Note that It is not necessary for text delimiters to appear at the very end of receipts. Instead, as long as they appear after the payment block would be fine.

Multiple delimiters can be added for one capturing instance. However, you should make sure that, for one receipt, one and only one of the delimiters will appear. For example, if you set two delimiters: one is the paper cut command and the other is text printed at the end of receipts, it is possible that one receipt will be interpreted as two. It is, however, OK to add multiple paper cut commands as delimiters, as only one of them will be used.

You can read more about [e-receipts on POS machines with our proprietary driver and SDK](http://mytapi.com/tutorial/pos-side-development-and-deployment/)

Answer (score 0):

For OPOSPrinter, this worked for me

```
string GS = Convert.ToString((char)29);
                string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);
                string COMMAND = "";
                COMMAND = ESC + "@";
                COMMAND += GS + "V" + (char)1;
oposPrinter.PrintNormal(2, COMMAND);
```