# POS receipt print cannot make paper cut using python

Tags: python, usb, receipt, pos, posprinter

**Problem**

We are working on a bigger project where we need to make a POS receipt print. We are
able to make a print through the browser but the problem is that we cannot make a cut or a
partial cut.

**Win32 API**

We have tried with Win32 API which work as well but we cannot find a command telling the
receipt printer to "cut".

We have tried the following with win32:

```py
from win32 import win32api
import win32print
txt = " Hello test ".encode()
p = win32print.OpenPrinter("EPSON TM-T20II Receipt")
job = win32print.StartDocPrinter (p, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
win32print.StartPagePrinter (p)
win32print.WritePrinter (p, txt)
win32print.EndPagePrinter (p)
win32print.ClosePrinter(p)
```

We have tried ending the print with these commands, without any luck.

```py
win32print.EndDoc(p)
win32print.EndPagePrinter(p) 
win32print.EndDocPrinter(p11)
```

**Other commands**

Then we found other web pages saying that we should send a specific command to the printer, to make the cut. In that approach we had to initialise the printer differently. We made a few tries to do that.

```py
p = printer.Usb( 0x04b8 , 0x0202 )
```

That gave the error `NoBackendError`, which was solved by installing
`libusb-win32-devel-filter-1.2.6.0.exe`, and then we got `USBNotFoundError`.

Then we tried

```py
p = Usb( 0x04b8 , 0x0202 , 0 , profile="TM-T20II")
```

Which said: `Unexpected keyword argument 'profile'`.

We did a little to solve that, but didn’t succeed.

Then we wrote:

```py
from escpos.connections import getUSBPrinter
p = getUSBPrinter()(idVendor= 0x1504,
                    idProduct= 0x0006,
                    inputEndPoint= 0x82,
                    outputEndPoint= 0x01)
```

With the error: `Cable isn’t plugged in`. Tried to install a `libusb-win32`filter, again without luck.

Went back to the win32 Api, and found these links:
[C# CUSTOM VKP80iii Paper Ejector/Paper Cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550276/c-sharp-custom-vkp80iii-paper-ejector-papercut)
[What is the paper cut command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671045/what-is-the-paper-cut-command)
https://mike42.me/blog/what-is-escpos-and-how-do-i-use-it

Okay, the mindset now is to make a command to the pos print. We knew that commands to the pos print, wasn’t our best thing, but the idea was that the text was sent to the printer with the commands:

- 1. try 
     ○ cutTxt = "0001 1100 0101 1000 0000 0101 0000 0001 0100 0101 
             0000 0101".encode()
- 2. try 
      
     ○ cutTxt = bytearray("28 80 5 1 69 5", "utf-8")
- 3. try
     ○ GS = str( 29 ) 
     ○ ESC = str( 27 ) 
     ○ cutTxt = "" 
     ○ cutTxt = ESC + "@" 
     ○ cutTxt += GS + "V"
- Followed by 
  ○ win32print.WritePrinter (p, cutTxt) 
   
  It just printed exactly what we wrote to the printer

**Settings**

Last but not least, we found the pos printer on the computer, went into the settings, to see if there was some settings we could change to make it cut. And you guessed it, we had no success.
But we tried to print some test prints, and when doing that, it made the partial cut without any problem.

Comment: https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/escpos/escpos.html#Escpos.cut

Answer (score 0):

For full cut

```
win32print.WritePrinter(p, b'\x1dV\x00')
```

For partial cut

```
win32print.WritePrinter(p, b'\x1dV\x01')
```

Answer (score 0):

For cutting in EPSON TM-T2... POS printers, this worked for me.

```
win32print.WritePrinter (p, txt)
win32print.WritePrinter (p, b"\x1B@\x1DV1")
win32print.EndPagePrinter (p)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**